# How to modify this command to vertically align a table cell?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

This minimal code example:

```
\documentclass[helvetica,portuguese,narrow]{europecv}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{europecv}
        \ecvlanguageheader{(*)}
        \ecvlanguage{English}{\ecvCOne}{\ecvCOne}{\ecvBTwo}{\ecvBTwo}{\ecvCOne}
        \ecvlanguagefooter{(*)}
    \end{europecv}
\end{document}
```

Produces the following document:
[image]

What I want is to vertically align those `C1` and `B2`.

I looked through the `europecv` package and found that I can add the following to my document to rewrite the command that outputs those table rows:

```
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand*\ecvCEF[2]{
        \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\footnotesize}p{.2\ecv@langparwidth}@{\hspace{1mm}}>{\footnotesize\centering}p{.74\ecv@langparwidth}@{}}
             #1 & #2\tabularnewline
        \end{tabular}
    }
\makeatother
```

That is the original code, I just need to find how to properly **vertically align** those `C1` and `B2` to the **middle of the cell**. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what you mean by "properly aligning" the C1 and B2 items? (They all look nicely aligned to each other...) Do you maybe want to center them vertically relative to the two rows that are immediately next to them?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Sorry, I didn't make that clear enough...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite straight forward.  You found the relevant command and the `europcv` package already loads `array` which provides an `m` column type for vertical alignement.  Renewing the command replacing `p` by `m` gives vertically centered labels:

```
\documentclass[helvetica,portuguese,narrow]{europecv}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\ecvCEF[2]{
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\footnotesize}m{.2\ecv@langparwidth}@{\hspace{1mm}}
   >{\footnotesize\centering}m{.74\ecv@langparwidth}@{}}
#1 & #2\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{europecv}
        \ecvlanguageheader{(*)}
        \ecvlanguage{English}{\ecvCOne}{\ecvCOne}{\ecvBTwo}{\ecvBTwo}{\ecvCOne}
        \ecvlanguagefooter{(*)}
    \end{europecv}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]